# How to scrape or extract from sources tab of chrome

Tags: python

I need to **scrape** from sources tab of chrome.

when inspected, there are 5 tabs

elements, console, sources, network etc.

now in sources, from the page tab i want to extract a line programatically.

I need this to be done in python and its libs.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap

Comment: What about using beautifulsoup, for example?